# How to develop a menu for Linux apps

Tags: python, linux

I want to create a python panel for Linux like pypanel or tint2 just for fun and to do practice with python development.

Now the problem is:

I want to create an auto-generated menu, but I don't know where to start.

Where can I find all user's installed software in a Linux distro? I know I should look in the `/usr/bin` folder, but I don't know if it's really the best thing to do.

Is there a way to filter installed apps to avoid dependecies programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a somewhat standardized way of doing this that many Linux desktop environments follow. Look in the directories `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications` for files with names that end in `.desktop`. Each of these files will correspond to one program and should look something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sample Application Name
Comment=A sample application
Exec=application
Icon=application.png
Terminal=false
```

You can parse these files to get the information to populate your menu.

For more infomation, see http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en